# Article Tags shown in Article List-Layout

Tags: joomla, tags, joomla3.0, article

So I've been adding tags you add to articles in Joomla!, which works fine. But now I want to show the tags in the article list layout that is default in Joomla.

I found and made an override for the list-layout and tried to add the tags code from a single article layout to the list-layout. Underneath is the code I tried to add in the list-layout. But none of the tags are shown in the layout..

```
<?php
    // set tags
    $tags = '';
    if (!empty($this->item->tags->itemTags)) {
        JLoader::register('TagsHelperRoute', JPATH_BASE . '/components/com_tags/helpers/route.php');
        foreach ($this->item->tags->itemTags as $i => $tag) {
            if (in_array($tag->access, JAccess::getAuthorisedViewLevels(JFactory::getUser()->get('id')))) {
                if($i > 0) $tags .= ', ';
                $tags .= '<a href="'.JRoute::_(TagsHelperRoute::getTagRoute($tag->tag_id . ':' . $tag->alias)).'">'.$this->escape($tag->title).'</a>';
            }
        }
    }
    $args['tags'] = $tags;
?>
```

If this isn't clear, I can try to explain it a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `php` works in the sense that it builds a set of "tag" links but it doesn't actually `echo` it out to the page. You need to add this line either at the end of your code or somewhere after, where you want to display the tags.

```
echo $tags;
```

e.g.

```
<?php
// set tags
$tags = '';
if (!empty($this->item->tags->itemTags)) {
    JLoader::register('TagsHelperRoute', JPATH_BASE .     '/components/com_tags/helpers/route.php');
    foreach ($this->item->tags->itemTags as $i => $tag) {
        if (in_array($tag->access,     JAccess::getAuthorisedViewLevels(JFactory::getUser()->get('id')))) {
            if($i > 0) $tags .= ', ';
            $tags .= '<a href="'.JRoute::_(TagsHelperRoute::getTagRoute($tag-    >tag_id . ':' . $tag->alias)).'">'.$this->escape($tag->title).'</a>';
        }
    }
}
$args['tags'] = $tags;
echo $tags;
?>
```

I'm not sure what you're using `$args` for either, it could probably be removed, unless you're using somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, you answered my question for the most part! I also had to change this line $this->item->tags->itemTags as $i => $tag to $article->tags->itemTags as $i => $tag). Now it shows the tags in the list-layout!