# Show Article Tags in the Category List Layout

Tags: php, listview, joomla, joomla3.0

I am developing a site using joomla 3.2.3 where I've been adding some tags to my joomla articles that in the articles is displayed above it's content.

For listing I use the 'Menu Item Type: Articles > Category List' and I would like to have it display the articles Tags in the list as well, e.g. like this:

[Title] [Author] [Tags]

Since joomla doesn't support this option in the article manager option to show tags in the List-Layout, I've been trying to add it to the list by editing the List-Layout files.
Here I made a template override of:

com_content > Category

Which includes the list-files:

- default.php
- default.xml
- default_article.php
- default_children.php

Then I've tried modifying this file, which creates the list-layout:

.../templates/my_template/html/com_content/category/default_articles.php

To create the tag column for the list-layout I added this code in the section around line 100:

```
<?php if ($this->params->get('show_tags')) : ?>
   <th id="categorylist_header_tags">
         <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort', 'JTAG', 'tags', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
   </th>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This created and displays a 2nd column in my category list view with the header title: Tags (if set to 'show' in Article Manager Option)

And to get the tags to display in the column fields, I figured that i need to add a code for the tags in the section around line 181, where I tried adding this code:

```
   </td>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($this->params->get('show_tags', 1)) : ?>
   <<td headers="categorylist_header_tags" class="list-tags">
      <?php $this->item->tagLayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags'); ?>
      <?php echo $this->item->tagLayout->render($this->item->tags->itemTags); ?>
         <?php echo JText::sprintf('JTAG', $article->tags->itemTags); ?>
   </td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is the code I need help with, since it doesn't fully work, it only shows the text 'tags' (from the 'JTAG') in the fields, and doesn't display the article's tag from the code:

```
<?php $this->item->tagLayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags'); ?>
<?php echo $this->item->tagLayout->render($this->item->tags->itemTags); ?>
```

which I took from the Articles view default layout to see how the tags are rendered.
But this code apperently doesn't directly work in the Category list Layout or doesn't give any effect.

---

Tried to take a look at this post:
[Article Tags shown in Article List-Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972885/article-tags-shown-in-article-list-layout/19974968#19974968?newreg=f13cbf3bced9418992acc3f47c8801d9)

But have not been able to get the code in this post to work for me:

Comment: Please show the exact code you are using and also check to see if you have a layout override for that view.

Comment: Have updated my question for what I've done so far, where I have added the code's I'm using to try and get the tags to show.
I already created an override of the List-layout 'default_article.php' (mentioned in the beginning of the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you look at the weblinks category layout you'll see that tags for individual links are displaywed with this code:

```
<?php $tagsData = $item->tags->getItemTags('com_weblinks.weblink', $item->id); ?>
<?php if ($this->params->get('show_tags', 1)) : ?>
    <?php $this->item->tagLayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->item->tagLayout->render($tagsData); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So what you need to do is set up the $tagsData correctly changing the alias name and also making sure that the id variable is correct.

You put this inside the code for the layout of an individual item on the list meaning in the `blog_item.php` file possibly right after the title.

```
    <?php $this->item->tagLayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->item->tagLayout->render($this->item->tags->itemTags); ?>
```

Comment: Setting up the $tagsData I suppose you mean with this:

Comment: <?php $tagsData = $item->tags->getItemTags('alias-name', $item->id); ?>
Don't really know which is the correct alias name here, tried .e.g. 'com_tags.tag' and other but only resulting in the category list giving a fatal error with the message:
"Call to a member function getItemTags() on a non-object in Directory/templates/your_template/html/com_content/category/default_articles.php on line 184"

Comment: Still getting a fatal error from the $tagsData.
Please take a look on how my code(s) currently looks like in my question.
Have you tried testing if the code from the 'weblinks category layout' works in the 'category list layout' to show tags?

Comment: The code from weblinks give you the idea, I'm assuming you are making sure that the variables have the same names. I'm not writing the code for you, I'm showing you how to solve your problem. You may also want to look at the code in the featured layout.  YOu really need to step back and make sure you understand how JLayouts work

Comment: <?php $this->item->tagLayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags'); ?>
   <?php echo $this->item->tagLayout->render($this->item->tags->itemTags); ?>

worked for me just fine, though the first time i pasted it in it was at the bottom of hte article so I almost missed it.

Comment: Okay that's weird. For me it so far doesn't give any effect. Did you use that code the same way I did in my question? Could you maybe update your answer with the exact code and location you use to get it to work?

Comment: Okay I added a few more words to the bottom. Your code is redoing the query that has already been done, rather than just using the JLayout. There is no reason to do all that work when all you need to do is to add the call the the tags layout.

Comment: You say the blog_item.php? Not sure I'm following you right. I'm not using the category blog layout. I'm using the category list layout to list my articles, which is rendered by the file default_article.php.

Comment: So put it there. Whichever layout you are using. Also make sure you are doing this in an override not in the core file or you will lose it later.

Comment: I'm not having much luck with this. So not sure how to get it working. This is by the way a image of how I would like my Category list to show the tags: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p52fdwhmbb6hrnc/Example%20of%20tags%20displaying%20in%20category%20list%20layout.png

Comment: Ok so you are working in a copy of the default_items.php file that is located in your template right? What happens if you put `var_dump($article->tags->itemTags)` after the title link?  Also in the above code change $this->item to $article

Comment: Yes I am. Only that I don't got that file 'defualt_items.php' for my joomla (3.2.3), but have the file 'default_article.php' instead which I believe is the same file just with a different name, it is at least the file which renders the list. I'll try your code there and see what happens and report back.

Comment: changing '$this->item' to '$article' gives a fatal error.
as for the  'var_dump($article->tags->itemTags)' I'm not quite sure exactly where after the title link to put it. At those places I tried putting it, it eather had no effect or gave fatal error.
If you want to look into it, then this is have the entire code looks like: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8b02iiu0vbkysl0/Default_article.php.txt. My tags code is at line 184.

Comment: ok so ... let's start a bit simpler.  How much PHP do you know? You are putting $article inside the `<?php foreach ($this->items as $i => $article) : ?>` loop that defines `$article` right?
In a category list `$this` is going to refer to the category object not to the individual item objects.

Comment: Got it working now. Thanks a lot for giving me ideas. Not sure what I did wrong in the first place, since I'm pretty sure I tried the following many times, but changing <?php echo ...render($this->item->tags->itemTags); ?> to <?php echo ...render($article->tags->itemTags); ?> did now do the trick.
Have updated your answer.