# Joomla 3 add article tags to search results

Tags: php, html, joomla, joomla3.0

I would very much appreciate your help.

I am creating a site with Joomla 3.4. 
Articles that are tagged are not showing their tags in the search results. I'm not sure whether they should or not, but I have read the following answer:
[Article Tags shown in Article List-Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972885/article-tags-shown-in-article-list-layout/19974968#19974968?newreg=f13cbf3bced9418992acc3f47c8801d9)

I concluded that I should be able to add the following into the default_results.php page, which is similar:

```
            <?php
        // set tags
        $tags = '';
        if (!empty($result->item->tags->itemTags)) {
            JLoader::register('TagsHelperRoute', JPATH_BASE .     '/components/com_tags/helpers/route.php');
            foreach ($result->item->tags->itemTags as $i => $tag) {
                if (in_array($tag->access,     JAccess::getAuthorisedViewLevels(JFactory::getUser()->get('id')))) {
                    if($i > 0) $tags .= ', ';
                    $tags .= '<a href="'.JRoute::_(TagsHelperRoute::getTagRoute($tag->tag_id . ':' . $tag->alias)).'">'.$result->escape($tag->title).'</a>';
                }
            }
        }
        $args['tags'] = $tags;
        echo $tags;
        ?>
```

Could you amend this please or tell me where I am going wrong?

I have customised the search results a little but only to add the intro-image and have compared it to the non-overridden file and it is not showing any call to tag info.

I had a funny feeling that at the start of the build the search results displayed the tags as standard and now they are not. If that's the case then I need to go backward... The tags show in the article page so the whole module isn't broken, and I have enabled 'show tags' in as many place as possible - though of course that shouldn't make a difference with that code.

Can you help please?

Regards M

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the search query does not return the tags and so `$result->item->tags wil be empty. I think you probably will need to do a plugin to get the tags for all items displayed on a page (or slower, one at a time for each item on the page).

Comment: Thank you, Elin for you fast response and for taking the time to reply. Ok, I thought that calling the TagsHelperRoute took care of that by finding the tags for that item, as I presumed it did in the Article List layout. I guess not.

Comment: - this shows up some gaps large gaps in my knowledge.

Comment: Look in /libraries/cms/helper/tags and you well see that there is a method to get all the tags for a given item `getItemTags()`.

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you very much indeed. I will look into this later today.